# How to get an string which is inside multiple arrays in a JSON file via PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, request

I'm trying to get an string which is inside multiple arrays.

I looked for some examples but all of them show how to get a string inside an array not multiple arrays

**Json file:**

```
id: "<myid>"
name: "<myname>"
properties:
   0:
      name: "textures"
      value: "<value>" \\what I'm trying to get
```

**Php file:**

```php
$url_var = <url>;
$var_data = file_get_contents($url_var);
$var_decoded = json_decode($var_data, true);
$var = $var_decoded->properties->0->value;
```

I'm trying to get the value but every time I try it I get an error message from this line (The code sample below is only one of many ways I've tried):

```php
$var = $var_decoded->properties->0->value;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your JSON file doesn't actually look like JSON to me, but rather YAML.  In any case, you should use a _parser_ which can handle a file of this format.  Don't try to do this via regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used `true` as a second parameter inside the json_decode. You can access this as an array:

```
$var = $var_decoded['properties'][0]['value']
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast, I've already tried that but I should spell it wrong, now it's working!